# Precedence of python input() function

Tags: python, input

I have the following lines (using Spyder 4.1.4):

```
arr = np.arange(1,10)
plt.scatter(arr, arr)
ans = input('Type yes or no')
```

I would like the plot to appear *before* I'm asked to "Type yes or no", but the opposite occurs.

Is there something about `input` that makes it execute before the plot is displayed?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html

Comment: The plot should never appear though since you never call `plt.show()` or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
arr = np.arange(1,10)
plt.scatter(arr, arr)
plt.show()
ans = input('Type yes or no')
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks!

Comment: @user3124318: I'm glad to hear their solution solved your problem. Once you're able to, please be sure to mark this answer as accepted—and, if you found it valuable, upvote it. That will help validate the answer for future readers, while also recognizing the contributor for their effort.